# VB.net how would you improve the performance of this function

Tags: vb.net, performance

I have this function which calculates suggested price for some product depending on available stock, now its not important what it doesn but its somehow and my program runs like x10 faster without it and i am really confused and i am not sure why it is slow

```
 Dim MinPrice As Double
    Dim VAT = 1.1899999999999999
    Dim margin1
    Dim potherrule1 As String
    Dim margin2
    Dim potherrule2 As String
    Dim margin3
    Dim potherrule3 As String
    Dim defaultmargin

    If SupplierMargin IsNot Nothing Then
        margin1 = SupplierMargin(0)
        potherrule1 = SupplierPother(0)
        margin2 = SupplierMargin(1)
        potherrule2 = SupplierPother(1)
        margin3 = SupplierMargin(2)
        potherrule3 = SupplierPother(2)
        defaultmargin = SupplierMargin(3)
    End If


    If IsDBNull(CurrentPother) Or (potherrule1 = "x" And potherrule2 = "x" And potherrule3 = "x") Then
        MinPrice = Math.Round((oprice / (1 - defaultmargin)) * VAT, 2)
        Return MinPrice
    End If

    If Not IsDBNull(CurrentPother) Then
        If potherrule1 <> "x" Then
            Dim v1 As Integer
            Dim v2 As Integer
            Dim rule As String = potherrule1
            Dim parts() As String = rule.Split(New String() {" bis "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
            v1 = Integer.Parse(parts(0))
            v2 = Integer.Parse(parts(1))
            If CurrentPother >= v1 And CurrentPother <= v2 Then
                MinPrice = Math.Round((oprice / (1 - margin1)) * VAT, 2)
            End If
            Return MinPrice

        ElseIf potherrule2 <> "x" Then
            Dim v1 As Integer
            Dim v2 As Integer
            Dim rule As String = potherrule2
            Dim parts() As String = rule.Split(New String() {" bis "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
            v1 = Integer.Parse(parts(0))
            v2 = Integer.Parse(parts(1))
            If CurrentPother >= v1 And CurrentPother <= v2 Then
                MinPrice = Math.Round((oprice / (1 - margin2)) * VAT, 2)
                Return MinPrice
            End If

        ElseIf potherrule2 <> "x" Then
            Dim v1 As Integer
            Dim v2 As Integer
            Dim rule As String = potherrule3
            Dim parts() As String = rule.Split(New String() {" bis "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
            v1 = Integer.Parse(parts(0))
            v2 = Integer.Parse(parts(1))
            If CurrentPother >= v1 And CurrentPother <= v2 Then
                MinPrice = Math.Round((oprice / (1 - margin3)) * VAT, 2)
                Return MinPrice
            End If
        Else
            MinimumPriceWhenPother4IsDBnull(SupplierMargin, oprice)
        End If
    End If
```

can you please suggest some improvements that could make this function faster?

Comment: Set `Option Strict` to on, avoid `ArrayList`, instead use a `List(Of Double)` for `SupplierMargin` and a `List(Of String)` for `SupplierPother`.

Comment: the arraylists i send to this function are saved in My.Setting i can't seem to find `System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Double)` in My.Settings

Comment: @user1570048: Ok, but even then it's still possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951876/can-you-have-a-generic-listof-t-in-your-settings-file

Comment: @user1570048.  Does your code actually return a value every time?  To me, it looks like if a rule doesn't equal 'x', and the currentPother is not in the v1 to v2 range, then nothing gets returned (unless it is potherrule1, in which case it will return a 0).  Either way, follow Tim Schmelter's advice, and also maybe make those evaluations a function itself to "getMinPrice".

Comment: @APrough if nothing non of the conditions were true then MinimumPriceWhenPother4IsDBnull(SupplierMargin, oprice) always returns something

Comment: @user1570048 - it may always return something, but if MinimumPriceWhenPother4IsDBNull takes longer than the If statements to run, that could contribute to your speed issue.  I was jsut trying to point out that your 1st and 2nd ElseIf were relying upon the same criteria.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Tim Schmelter's comment above, you do realize your third conditional is still looking at potherrule2?  Because of this, my guess is that your code is defaulting to your MinimumPriceWhenPother4IsDBnull function when potherrule3 is <> "x" and you want it to evaluate.  Not sure what that function does, but if it is running a lot, that could account for your speed issue.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @APrough that the issue is likely due to your third ElseIf making the wrong comparison and then the method dropping down to `MinimumPriceWhenPother4IsDBnull(SupplierMargin, oprice)` unexpectedly. What are you doing in that method? Is it possible you're reading from a database at that point?

Each of your first three If handlers could be factored out into another method to increase code reuse. It wouldn't increase perf though.

Another point of warning. Watch out for Math.Round. By default it uses the ANSI standard rounding to the nearest even rather than rounding you learned in school. See http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/Rounding-in-.Net. This wouldn't be a cause for a 10x perf degradation though.

Additionally, you may want to run the performance analysis in VS ultimate, or grab an eval of the Ants profiler to see where the real bottleneck is in your code. It can often be hidden by event handlers, behind method calls, or other unexpected places.