# Settings file types

Tags: c#, settings

I use the built-in Settings file to store the state of controls on form.

I use `System.collections.Specialized.StringCollection` and would like to use a list of int values.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: This is a way to avoid dynamically enum initializing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `List<T>` in the settings, so you have to convert it yourself:

```
var strings = Properties.Settings.Default.Strings; // your StringCollection 
List<int> ints = strings.Cast<string>().Select(str => int.Parse(str)).ToList();
```

Comment: So there is no way to implement a custom list type in the Settings? This is a detour...

Comment: @user3165438: there might be a way as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951876/can-you-have-a-generic-listof-t-in-your-settings-file) but i haven't tried it. The easiest is to use the string-collection and parse them once at application start.