# Dictionary in Settings throws an exception?

Tags: c#, exception, dictionary, settings

I want to save a dictionary in the default UserSettings class of my project.

I've tried the following in the code of the Settings file but it fails:

```
<Setting Name="MediaKeys" Type="System.Collections.ObjectModel.Dictionary&lt;System.Input.Key, System.IO.FileInfo&gt;" Scope="User">
  <Value Profile="(Default)" />
</Setting>
```

I get this error message when I look at the UI for the Settings:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.FileInfo>' or one of its
>   dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

Bearing in mind, please, that I will deal with the whole Serializable Dictionary at another point in time, why am I getting this exception? Even non-serializable objects (such as FileInfo, as I have tested) do not throw this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET settings do not handle generics very well.  This is what I do:

```
[XmlRoot("dictionary")]
public class MyDictionary : SerializableDictionary<int, string>
{
}
```

Comment: This is not a viable solution. The settings class contains many settings objects. Also; I have success with ObservableCollections. Is it possible that the ',' character in the XML string needs to be escaped? (That is my initial suspicion, but I have not been able to figure out how to escape a comma in an XML string)

Comment: @Will I think this is the best option but you can try to kludge it.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4046036/3980331).